# Is there any way to get feeds from public facebook pages using spring social, restfb, etc

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to get feeds of public facebook pages in my java application. I am using graph api.
I keep getting an error. Error listed below.

I have generated the access token several times.

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("my access token goes here", Version.VERSION_4_0);

User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("cocacola", Page.class,
        Parameter.with("fields", "fan_count"));

out.println("User name: " + user.getName());
out.println("Page likes: " + page.getFanCount());
```

> Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook

Answer (score 2):

Like the error response says to read public page data your app needs to reviewed and approved for Page Public Content Access, you cannot access/read public page data w/o it. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS